# Angular ....error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms, angular-material

Error: src/app/form-page/form-page.component.html:1:29 - error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

<mat-form-field (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"  class="form-register">
~~~~~~~~

```
    src/app/form-page/form-page.component.ts:8:16
```

templateUrl: './form-page.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component FormPageComponent.

this is my html code

````
```
       <mat-form-field (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"  class="form-register">
        <p>
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
          <input  matInput
            type="text" 
            placeholder="First Name"
            ngModel
            required>
        </mat-form-field>
     </p>
     <p>
       <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
       <mat-label>Last Name</mat-label>
       <input matInput 
         placeholder="Last Name"
         ngModel
         required>
       </mat-form-field>
   </p>
    <p>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Age</mat-label>
      <input matInput 
         placeholder="Age"
         ngModel
         required>
     </mat-form-field>
   </p>
   <p>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Gender</mat-label>
      <mat-select ngModel required>
          <mat-option>Male</mat-option>
          <mat-option>Female</mat-option>
          <mat-option>Transgender</mat-option>
          <mat-option>Prefer Not To Say</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
  </p>
  <p>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Mobile Number</mat-label>
      <input matInput 
         placeholder="Mobile Number"
         ngModel
         required>
    </mat-form-field>
   </p>

         <button mat-button (click)="creationDone()"> Submit</button>

   </mat-form-field>
````

this is my ts code

```
     import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild,Inject } from '@angular/core';
     import { FormControl, FormGroup, NgForm, NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
     import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef,MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';


      @Component({
       selector: 'app-form-page',
       templateUrl: './form-page.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./form-page.component.scss']
       })
      export class FormPageComponent {
         @ViewChild('f') userform:NgForm;
          onSubmit(form){
               console.log(form.value);
           }
        constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}
          creationDone() {
            this.dialog.open(SubmitDialog);
               }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In your ts file, you have declared the `onSubmit(form)` function which expects an argument form.

```
onSubmit(form){
    console.log(form.value);
}
```

But in your .html file, you are calling the function without passing any arguments. Hence you are getting this error.

Comment: how do I fix this? I'm new in this angular?

Comment: Check the other answer. It should clear any confusions.

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition requires one argument whereas you are passing none in your HTML file while calling the function. You can do one of the following to successfully run the code:

1. Change the calling of the function

```
...
<mat-form-field (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userform)"  class="form-register">
...
```

2. or remove the argument of the function

```
onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.userform.value);
}
```

It will work with one of these ways. Totally your call.